# Single servlet mapped multiple times in web.xml

Tags: spring, servlets

I have come accross some existing code where in web.xml a single servlet is mapped multiple times. I dont understand the need of doing so.

e.g.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>test1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.test.spring.MyDispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>test2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.test.spring.MyDispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>test3</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.test.spring.MyDispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume if you have different url-pattern for each servlet, you can combine that into a single url-pattern.

If the url-patterns are same, then you can remove the redundant mappings.

As far I know, adding the same servlet mapping multiple times is not useful or not needed.

This [post](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html) discussed in detail about servlet mapping. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. 
The url pattern are different.

e.g.

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test1/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test3</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test3/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```